# Merkle path authentication

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, hash-tree

In [point 4 of the Algorithm 4.2 (Classic Merkle Tree Traversal) of *"Post_Quantum_Cryptography.pdf"*](http://www.e-reading-lib.com/bookreader.php/135832/Post_Quantum_Cryptography.pdf) shows *"Stack_h.update(2)"* each stack receives two updates. I am trying understand to understand why there are "two updates" but I don't. There is an example on [page 19 of *"Boris_Ederov.bachelor.Merkle-Tree-Traversal-Techniques.pdf"*](https://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/reports/reports/Boris_Ederov.bachelor.Merkle-Tree-Traversal-Techniques.pdf). In that thesis, it only updates one time. For example in the step 1. Why update stack one time?

```
Step 1: leaf=0
"For h=0 we run 0 Stack_0.update  , which only computes P_n(3), puts it onto the stack and stops."
```